# html2Canvas download is blurry how can i make it clearer

Tags: javascript, jquery, project, html2canvas

I am using HTML2Canvas and it works fine but the download is kind of blurry and I am wondering how to fix it here is my code.

```
 function html2img2pdf() {
    html2canvas($(".resume-results"), {
      onrendered: function (canvas) {
        var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        var doc = new jsPDF;
        doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 20, 20);
        doc.save("resume.pdf");
      }
    })
  }
```

Here is my html code

```
</body>
<script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.debug.js" 
integrity="sha384- 
CchuzHs077vGtfhGYl9Qtc7Vx64rXBXdIAZIPbItbNyWIRTdG0oYAqki3Ry13Yzu" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="../JS/resume/general-industry.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't know if it's it but `toDataURL` takes a second argument: `quality: 0-1` default is `0.8` in some browsers

Comment: @Endless what do you recommend that I use instead of toDataURL

Comment: `canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1)`

Comment: @Endless I have made the changes but it still seems to be blurry

Comment: Dose it look blurry after you have appended it to the pdf? maybe you did downscale or upscaled the image? Also you are getting the image as a png and adding it to the doc as JPEG... maybe you meant to do `doc.addImage(img, 'PNG', 20, 20)` or `canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1)`